# Monte carlo simulation to forecast growth of a loan portfolio

Tags: forecasting, monte-carlo, deterministic

I have to forecast the future gold loan portfolio growth of a financial firm. I have past 36 month growth data.

I am planning to use Monte Carlo simulation to forecast, but growth is a deterministic process not a random process. How can I apply Monte Carlo for this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your model is deterministic and no randomness or uncertainty, there’s no point with simulation because all your paths will be identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. I had better study detail about montecarlo.